# Polymer 2.x or 1.x for a new project

Tags: javascript, polymer, progressive-web-apps

I will start a pwa project right now. I will use Firebase for hosting and backend and Polymer. I am a novice in Polymer (and pwa). The app requirements include Google and Facebbok authentication, Chat for the users and some real-time informations. Should I use Polymer 2.x or 1.x?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the place to ask this. Please check the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend 1.x for production until 2.x is finally released (it's in [RC](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.2) at the moment). Several Polymer components available from the community have not yet been upgraded to 2.x, so using 2.x may limit your component choices for now.

Note that 2.x has a [1.x compatibility layer](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/about_20#polymer-1-compatibility-layer), and they're planning a migration tool (similar to the [`polyup`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration#polyup-tool) tool for 1.x) to automatically upgrade your code, so theoretically, the upgrade path should be relatively painless.

If you're just experimenting or you don't mind development churn, go for 2.x to minimize the potential changes later.